# Nginx configuration for WordPress fpm-alpine

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to optimize my server Nginx performance, but I cannot figure out how.
my server is ubuntu 20.04, and I have an Nginx installed locally and use it to reverse proxy to my 2 websites.

my native Nginx config for redirect to website1 is like this:

```
server {
    listen 80; listen [::]:80;
    server_name website1.com www.website1.com;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 5M;     # --> Maximum 5MB file is allowed to upload
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9191/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
 }
}
```

and website1 is set up with the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  # Database for wordpress mysql
  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db_name
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    networks:
      - ntk

  # Wordpress service
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
      - redis
    image: wordpress:fpm-alpine
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql_db:3308
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=stsecret_db_name
      - WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA=
           define('WP_REDIS_HOST','redis');
           define('WP_REDIS_PORT','9649');
           define('WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT','password');
           define('WP_CACHE','true');

    volumes:
      - wp:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - ntk
      
  # Nginx webserver
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9191:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - wp:/var/www/html

    networks:
      - ntk
           
  # Redis 
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9649:9649
      
    volumes:
      - rd:/var/www/html
             
    networks:
      - ntk          
    entrypoint: redis-server --maxmemory 256mb --maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
  
volumes:
  db:
  wp:
  rd:
networks:
  ntk:
    driver: bridge
```

and the docker Nginx configuration for website1 that is passed on:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name server_name website1.ir www.website1.ir;

    # Gzip configuration
    gzip on;
    gzip_static on; # allows pre-serving of .gz file if it exists
    gzip_disable "msie6"; # Disable for user-agent Internet explorer 6. Not supported.
    gzip_proxied any; # enable gzip for all proxied requests
    gzip_buffers 16 8k; # number and size of buffers to compress a response
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 256; # Only gzip files of size in bytes
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/html application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript $
    gunzip on; # Uncompress on the fly

    # Wordpress
    location / {
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        root /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        root /var/www/html;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize=128M \n post_max_size=128M";
    }
}
```

I want to modify my Nginx according to this [tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/powerful-ways-to-supercharge-your-nginx-server-and-improve-its-performance-a8afdbfde64d/), but I have 2 questions that I cannot find the answer to.

1. even though everything works right now, but isn't using 2 Nginx redundant? I mean, can I use the locally installed Nginx and get rid of the docker Nginx? and if yes, how? I tried to run docker-compose without the Nginx and exposing WordPress 9191 port to outside, so Nginx could directly redirect to it, but it didn't work!
2. if using 2 Nginx is mandatory, where should I add the things that are mentioned in this [tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/powerful-ways-to-supercharge-your-nginx-server-and-improve-its-performance-a8afdbfde64d/), like Micro caching, Pagespeed Module and rate limit? should it be added to the local Nginx or the one inside the docker ?

Thanks.